# Tictactoe game code

Tags: javascript, html, tic-tac-toe

I created this game for many hours. I finished it without any syntax error.

I try to play it but it doesn't work. I don't know why? Is there any problem with my code?

```html
<script>
  function startTac() {
    var t1 = document.getElementById("1");
    var t2 = document.getElementById("2");
    var t3 = document.getElementById("3");
    var t4 = document.getElementById("4");
    var t5 = document.getElementById("5");
    var t6 = document.getElementById("6");
    var t7 = document.getElementById("7");
    var t8 = document.getElementById("8");
    var t9 = document.getElementById("9");
    var plyr = "X";
    if ((t1.innerHTML) == (t2.innerHTML) && (t2.innerHTML) == (t3.innerHTML) || (t4.innerHTML) == (t5.innerHTML) && (t5.innerHTML) == (t6.innerHTML) || (t7.innerHTML) == (t8.innerHTML) && (t8.innerHTML) == (t9.innerHTML)) {
      alert("Game Over");
    }
  }
  if ((t1.innerHTML) == (t4.innerHTML) && (t4.innerHTML) == (t7.innerHTML) || (t2.innerHTML) == (t5.innerHTML) && (t5.innerHTML) == (t8.innerHTML) || (t3.innerHTML) == (t6.innerHTML) && (t6.innerHTML) == (t9.innerHTML)) {
    alert("Game Over");
  }
  }
  if ((t1.innerHTML) == (t5.innerHTML) && (t5.innerHTML) == (t9.innerHTML) || (t3.innerHTML) == (t5.innerHTML) && (t5.innerHTML) == (t7.innerHTML)) {
    alert("Game Over");
  }
  }

  function gameTac(tar) {
    switch (plyr) {
      case "X":
        {
          document.getElementById(tar).innerHTML = "O";
          document.getElementById(tar).setAtrribute(" onclick", "");
          plyr = "O";startTac();
          break;
        }
      case "O":
        {
          document.getElementById(tar).innerHTML = "X";
          document.getElementById(tar).setAtrribute(" onclick", "");
          plyr = "X";startTac();
          break;
        }
    }
  }
</script>
<table border="1" width="400px" height="400px" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td id="1" onclick="gameTac(this.id)"></td>
      <td id="2" onclick="gameTac(this.id)"></td>
      <td id="3" onclick="gameTac(this.id)">H</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="4" onclick="gameTac(this.id)"></td>
      <td id="5" onclick="gameTac(this.id)"></td>
      <td id="6" onclick="gameTac(this.id)"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="7" onclick="gameTac(this.id)"></td>
      <td id="8" onclick="gameTac(this.id)"></td>
      <td id="9" onclick="gameTac(this.id)"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Can anyone fix my code?

I cannot fix my code because I'm creating this on android. Thank you!

Comment: Please help!!!!!!!!

Comment: What is the problem you are facing with?

Comment: I doubt about your if condition. Please double check that

Answer (score 1):

Simply put: your code has a lot of errors... (refer to other answers for specifics). Here is some code you that will get your game working and i'll leave to you to complete.

```
var plyr = "X";

function startTac() {
    var t1 = document.getElementById("1");
    var t2 = document.getElementById("2");
    var t3 = document.getElementById("3");
    var t4 = document.getElementById("4");
    var t5 = document.getElementById("5");
    var t6 = document.getElementById("6");
    var t7 = document.getElementById("7");
    var t8 = document.getElementById("8");
    var t9 = document.getElementById("9");

    let tiles = [0, t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6, t7, t8, t9]
    let winningPaths = [
        [1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],
        [1,4,7],[2,5,8],[3,6,9],
        [1,5,9],[3,5,7]
    ]

    winningPaths.forEach(path => {
        let matchingTiles = path.filter(id => {
            let tile = tiles[id]

            if(tile.textContent === plyr) {
              return true
            } else {
              return false
            }

      }).length

      if(matchingTiles === 3) {
        alert("Game Over")
      }
    })

  }    

  function gameTac(tar) {
    switch (plyr) {
      case "X":
      {
          document.getElementById(tar).textContent = "O";
          document.getElementById(tar).onclick = undefined;
          plyr = "O";
          startTac();
          break;
      }
      case "O":
      {
          document.getElementById(tar).textContent = "X";
          document.getElementById(tar).onclick = undefined;
          plyr = "X";
          startTac();
          break;
        }
    }
  }
```

Comment: What is the reason for using `var` on your singular variables and `let` on your arrays? I've never used `let` and I'm just wondering if i should start.

Comment: I just copied and pasted OP code and didn't realize the `var`s at the top. You should definitely stop using `var`and instead opt for `let` or `const` for all your variables. `let` and `const` work slightly differently then `var`. `let` is block-scoped, while `var` is function scoped. `const` works like variables in other languages like java as in once a `const` is declared, you can't redeclare that variable to a new value. Heres a good video on the matter: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sjyJBL5fkp8

Answer (score 0):

My first thought is that you need to double check then make sure your conditions is correct:

```
if ( (t1.innerHTML == t2.innerHTML && t2.innerHTML == t3.innerHTML) || (t4.innerHTML == t5.innerHTML && t5.innerHTML == t6.innerHTML) || (t7.innerHTML == t8.innerHTML && t8.innerHTML == t9.innerHTML)) {
      alert("Game Over");
}
```

And:

```
if ((t1.innerHTML == t4.innerHTML && t4.innerHTML == t7.innerHTML) || (t2.innerHTML == t5.innerHTML && t5.innerHTML == t8.innerHTML) || (t3.innerHTML == t6.innerHTML && t6.innerHTML == t9.innerHTML)) {
    alert("Game Over");
}
```

And:

```
  if ((t1.innerHTML == t5.innerHTML && t5.innerHTML == t9.innerHTML) || (t3.innerHTML == t5.innerHTML && t5.innerHTML == t7.innerHTML)) {
    alert("Game Over");
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You have a few extra `}`s in `startTac()`
2. Somebody decided once that you can't use numbers as Ids, seriously.
3. Take `var plyr = "X"` out of startTac(), put that line above it, otherwise the palyer gets reset to X every click.
4. `setAttribute("onclick","")` is misspelled in your code
5. Gonna have to work on your conditional blocks, they will trigger at the start because the empty cells are equal
6. Should probably say who won, when you have a game over.